# I don't know why I'm getting an out of bounds exception?

Tags: android, arrays

I don't know why this is generating an ArrayOutOfBoundsException! It's likely I've overlooked something because I'm so tired but if someone could tell me what is wrong I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

```
// array declaration
public int CircleLeft[] = new int[mIPAWidth];

// this is my loop that generates the error:
for(px = 0; px <= mIPAWidth - 1; px++){
py =(int) m.sqrt(r^2 - (px-mIPAWidthHalf)^2) + mIPAHeightHalf;
Log.w(getClass().getName(), "mIPAWidth = " + mIPAWidth + ", index is: " + px);
CircleLeft[px] = py; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with Luther Blissett's answer...

Are you modifying `mIPAWidth` between when the array is instantiated and when you begin the `for` loop? I would change your `for` conditional to something like this:

```
for(int px = 0; px < CircleLeft.length; px++)
```

That way you know the type of `px` and you know you're referencing the actual length of the `CircleLeft` array. It may not fix your error, but it's still a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think I may be referring to a variable that has a value that can change at runtime making access to an index in an already predefined array possibly throw an exception. I will change this now!

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of px? If it's a double, then you could suffer from a mis-compare with the `<=`(comparing for equality with double is almost never correct). Try the canonical loop `for(px = 0; px < mIPAWidth ; px++)` instead or better yet, make the loop index an integer.

Also, what's the type of `mIPAWidth` (for the same reasons)?

Comment: +1... it's another good reason to declare a new variable for your for loop counter.

Comment: I did in the initial stage of this loop use a seperate 'n' variable as the counter but I think the issue may reside in mIPAwidth also being dynamic as its value is reset when the surface changes and this loop is part of that method, configureGeometry...so I suppose if mIPAWidth was to change when the array has already been initialised, it would generate the outofbounds exception I am experiencing here!

Comment: @GG: This was suggested by iandisme, wasn't it? You should check his answer instead then (You can change the accepted answer IIRC).